Trying to write a code in C for a kaprekar routine. How can I fix the code to get a correct output for 85555?
I am trying to build a code in C that will go over the specified 4 numbers and will give an output based on their kaprekar process. If the number converges it should return the number it converges to, if it doesn't it should return -1. I am getting the correct result for all numbers but 85555, can someone help me identify the issue? I've tried to fix it but can't find what's wrong.
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_ROUNDS 1000
// Function declarations
long long kaprekar(long long n);
void arrayCountDigits(long long n, int* cArr);
long long sortDigits(int* cArr, int dir);

int main() {
    printf("%lld\n", kaprekar(11));         // Output: 0
    printf("%lld\n", kaprekar(85555));      // Wrong Output:74943 Should be 71973 
    printf("%lld\n", kaprekar(8991));       // Output: 6174
    printf("%lld\n", kaprekar(63317664));   // Output: 63317664

    return 0;
}

// Function to count digits of a number
void arrayCountDigits(long long n, int* cArr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cArr[i] = 0; // Initialize counts to zero
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        cArr[0] = 1;

    }
    while (n > 0) {
        cArr[n % 10]++;
        n /= 10;
    }
}

// Function to sort digits and form a number
long long sortDigits(int* cArr, int dir) {
    long long result = 0;
    if (dir == 0) { // Ascending order
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            while (cArr[i] > 0) {
                result = result * 10 + i;
                cArr[i]--; // Decrement digit count
            }
        }
    }
    else { // Descending order
        for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
            while (cArr[i] > 0) {
                result = result * 10 + i;
                cArr[i]--; // Decrement digit count
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Kaprekar function
long long kaprekar(long long n) {
    int cArr[10];
    long long nUp, nDown, nextN;
    int rounds = 0;

    while (rounds < MAX_ROUNDS) {
        arrayCountDigits(n, cArr);

        // Sort digits in ascending and descending order
        nUp = sortDigits(cArr, 0);

        // Reset the digit counts for descending sort
        arrayCountDigits(n, cArr);
        nDown = sortDigits(cArr, 1);

        // Compute the next number in the sequence
        nextN = nDown - nUp;

        // Break if the sequence converges or doesn't change
        if (nextN == n) {
            break;
        }
        n = nextN;
        rounds++;
    }

    return n;
}

Don't really know what else to try, the code works for the all numbers but 85555.

The question should explain what a kaprekar process is.

Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see where it diverges from your expectations?

Why do you think 71973 is a convergence? 97731-13779 = 83952

What if 0 is one of the digits in the number?

But 97443-34479 = 62,964, so it's not a fixed point, either.

The Kaprekar Routine takes a number, sorts its digits descending and ascending, subtracts them, and repeats.
For 5-digit numbers, The Kaprekar Routine either converges to 0 or one of the following three cycles:
53955, 59994
61974, 82962, 75933, 63954
62964, 71973, 83952, 74943

Here is the process for 85555:
85555 -> 85555 - 55558 = 29997
29997 -> 99972 - 27999 = 71973   # 3rd cycle above starts here
71973 -> 97731 - 13779 = 83952
83952 -> 98532 - 23589 = 74943
74943 -> 97443 - 34479 = 62964
62964 -> 96642 - 24669 = 71973   # and it repeats

So this code is wrong, as it assumes the number converges to one number, so the code runs for MAX_ROUNDS and happens to stop on a different number in the cycle:
        // Break if the sequence converges or doesn't change
        if (nextN == n) {
            break;
        }

I'll leave it as an exercise for the OP to fix.
